# In sentence, what does "their" indicate between women and men? and what does the sentence mean?

Tags: meaning, relative-pronouns

> As women come to consider being prized by men their ultimate source of
>   strength, worth, achievement and identity, they are compelled to
>   battle other women for the prize.

**Question**

1.I think the sentence means :

> As women come to consider their ultimate source of strength, worth,
>   achievement and identity at the same time being prized by men,they are
>   compelled to battle other women for the prize.

Is it right?

2.In sentence, what does "their" indicate between women and men?

Comment: As I read it, I think you are missing something - "being prized by men (due to) their ultimate source". Or possibly (for). Anyway, *their* refers to women.

Comment: First I thought there should be a comma before 'their ultimate'. But then after reading the whole sentence, it looks that there's something missing as user 3169 says

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a native speaker (Eastern US), I would read this as follows:

> As women come to consider being prized by men ...

This sets up the sentence, referring to a changing or developing state of the perception by women of the quality of being prized by men (that is to say the quality of a woman that is her being desired by men).

> their ultimate source of strength, worth, achievement and identity,

This, together with the previous quote, indicates that women at some point start to see the quality of being desired by men as the ultimate/underlying/fundamental/most important source of their "strength, worth, achievement and identity". The word "their" is identifying "strength, worth, achievement and identity", as belonging to women.

In summary, the sentence so far indicates that women at some point begin to view all of the "strength, worth, achievement and identity" that belongs to the women as being derived from the fact that the women are prized/desired by men.

Note: I do not at all agree with this sentence, and think it rather sexist.

> they are compelled to battle other women for the prize.

This concludes by saying that since women view their worth as coming from the fact that men desire women, the feel the need to fight each other to win the desire of men.